# Firestore web save data offline feedback

Tags: web, save, offline, google-cloud-firestore, feedback

I'm searching for a method to give feedback to a user of my Firebase/Firestore web app when offline. Lets see some code.

```
var colRef = db.collection('collectionName').doc('anyDoc');
var setWithMerge = colRef.set({
     'value': 'someValue',
 }, {
     merge: true
 })
 .then(function () {
     alert('Success');
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
     alert("Fail :" + error);
 });
```

**Online**: Call the function, and the success alert works perfect.

**Offline**: Call the function, and nothing happens. But when user goes online, the app shows all alerts in a row.

In short, the `.then` part of the code only runs online. I need some sort of feedback for offline user.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the expected behavior. Local write operations don't regularly fail, so there is no completion handler for them. If you want to do something after the local write completes, just use normal coding logic and put it after the `set`:

```
var colRef = db.collection('collectionName').doc('anyDoc');
var setWithMerge = colRef.set({
     'value': 'someValue',
 }, {
     merge: true
 })
 alert("Value set");
```

Comment: But can you be absolutely sure that even the local write has finished at this point? Is the data written before the (unfulfilled) promise is returned?

Comment: What I described is how the system is supposed to behave. If you're finding behavior that conflicts with what I said, please post or [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: We haven't, just curious. Good to know how its supposed to work.

Comment: Hi, well I am having a hard time with this behavior. 
The problem is that, I am saving, and at the end of this chain I need the response, with the id in order to save related data. I I dont have any feedback or the response of being saved, how can I cimplete the saving chain.
O the other cases, I need a feedback so I can close the view or do somenthing. May be I am missing somenthing here.

Answer (score 0):

Thx @Frank, @Blackwood.
I changed the alerts for a non blocking notification.

```
function doSomething() {
try {
    var colRef = db.collection('collectionName').doc('anyDoc');
    var setWithMerge = colRef.set({
            'value': 'someValue',
        }, {
            merge: true
        })
        .then(function () {
            alertify.notify('Data saved online.', 'success', 5);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            alert('Error: ' + error);//or
            //alertify.notify('Data saved online.', 'error', 10);
        });
    alertify.notify('Data saved on cache.', 'warning', 5);
} catch (error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error);
}}
```

Online: Call the function, and launches 2 notifies (cached and online) almost at same time.

Offline: Call the function, launches 1 notify and when user goes online, the app shows all pendent online notifies in a row.

A very acceptable behavior.
I do not speak English, forgive my mistakes.